# How to assigning jwt token to generate authentication on java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

How I can decode a token and assigning as string to match object?

Example:
User login with phone number and it will generate a jwt token when decoded this will be:

```
{
  "sub": "+440000010010" //can be any phone number
}
```

Then I need to get this phone number and compare to match field phoneNumber then it will generate a valid auth.

My code error is showing as incompatible types java.lang.string

My token handle generate and validate token

```
public String generate(String username) {

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public JwtUserDetails validate (String token) {
        JwtUserDetails jwtUserDetails = null;
        try {
            Claims body = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            jwtUserDetails = new JwtUserDetails(body.getSubject(), token);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jwtUserDetails;
    }

     public boolean validateToken(String token) {
            try {
                Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token);
                return true;
            } catch (SignatureException ex) {
                logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
            } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
                logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
                logger.error("Expired JWT token");
            } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
                logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

my filter is

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtTokenHandler.validateToken(jwt)) {

                String phoneNumber = jwtTokenHandler.validate(jwt) ;

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserPhone(username);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
         }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My whole code is generate and validate token as I tested but when I tried to match the values is give this error, anyone have an idea? I am still need on java spring.

Comment: Can you please add more of your code? What is within `jwtTokenHandler.validate(jwt);`?

Comment: Hi, I added my code of my jwtTokenHandler @MadhuBhat

Comment: In `String phoneNumber = jwtTokenHandler.validate(jwt) ;` how can it be assigned to `String` as the validate method returns `JwtUserDetails` object?

Comment: @MadhuBhat you're right! I changed to return as String instead object  and it does work like a charm! thank you!

Comment: Happy to be of help :)

Comment: @MadhuBhat I got stuck in one more step I would like to apply two auth in my filter... if you can help would be nice! I opened another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941420/how-to-use-if-else-statement-java-to-a-auth-filter